# How can i remove the repeating words in my html input field

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input id="btn-input" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Type your message here..." name="subject" pattern=".+?(?:[\s'].+?){2,}" autofocus required title="" />
```

**I have a problem with this, it is inserting when i insert repeating words like 
 college college college**
**and i also wanto to have a question format it is possible?**
**also open for java script suggestions even i already have**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works pretty good (when user pastes, inserts anything):

Code Snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<input id="btn-input" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Type your message here..." name="subject" pattern=".+?(?:[\s'].+?){2,}" autofocus required title="" />

<button id="toggleduplicates">Toggle allowing duplicates</button>


<script>

// I added this to allow duplicates
let allowDuplicates = false;

var element = document.getElementById("btn-input"),
togglebtn = document.getElementById("toggleduplicates");

function handler(e){
if(!allowDuplicates){
var userInput = element.value,
allWords =      userInput.split(" "),
searchedWords = [];

// Search thru all words (Indicating words by splitting the input in spaces, as done in the "allWords" variable)
for(i = 0; i < allWords.length; i++){

// If the current word (allWords[i]) already is in the searchedWords array
if(searchedWords.includes(allWords[i]))
element.value = element.value.replace(allWords[i] + " ", "");

// Adds the word to the list of used words
searchedWords.push(allWords[i]);
}}}

// Execute the function "handler" when the input field is updated
element.addEventListener("input", handler);

function toggleHandler(){
// Setting the allow duplicates boolean to the value that is not currently (true -> false / false -> true)
allowDuplicates = !allowDuplicates;

// Updates the input, in case it would include duplicates
handler();

alert("You may now " + (!allowDuplicates ? "NOT ":"") + "use duplicate words.");

}


// Execute the function "toggleHandler" when the button is clicked
togglebtn.addEventListener("click", toggleHandler);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how about allowing the stop words to duplicate?

Comment: I'll edit the code so that it can be easier changed

Comment: Edited the code so that you can toggle the "allow word duplicate" function